# How do you setup Clang and VS Code to compile for Linux on Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I am trying to set up a default VS Code project that I can copy and paste for C++ projects. I have installed Clang/LLVM and I have got a task in tasks.json that can build for Windows just fine. My problem is when I try to create task that would build for Linux by changing the --target variable to target for Linux on the same physical platform I end up getting an error that it is unable to find `<iostream>`. I am not sure if this is a tasks.json thing that I am getting wrong or a clang issue that I am unaware of. (I am very new to cross platforming)

My tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "Build Clang for Windows x64 (Debug)",
        "command": "clang++",
        "args": [
          "-std=c++17",
          "--target=x86_64-pc-win32-gnu",
          "-g",
          "${workspaceFolder}/Src/*.cpp",
          "-o",
          "${workspaceFolder}/Bin/Debug/Windows/x64/out.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
          "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "Build Clang for Linux x64 (Debug)",
        "command": "clang++",
        "args": [
          "-std=c++17",
          "-stdlib=libc++",
          "--target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu",
          "-g",
          "${workspaceFolder}/Src/*.cpp",
          "-o",
          "${workspaceFolder}/Bin/Debug/Linux/x64/out"
        ],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
          "$gcc"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: You need the actual environment to build for another platform. Easiest way is to actually build on that other platform. Second easiest way is to use WSL or some VM. Then it gets hard (possible, but quite some effort)

Comment: I was under the impression that Clang included the tools to cross compile to other platforms without having to set up additional environments.

Comment: @LouisChild - clang/llvm can effectively cross-compile, but they depend on things like a libc for the target platform. At minimum, you'll need the relevant C++ libraries for your linux platform (probably libstdc++) and libc (probably glibc).

Comment: @StephenNewell Ah, this makes more sense. So if I had those stored on my Windows machine somewhere I could point Clang/LLVM to them when compiling for Linux and in theory it should just work?